# Generate list of dates

Tags: sql

I want to get list of dates between two selected dates. for example if i select

date between 2013-05-28 and date 2014-01-01, the output should come like this

```
    2013-05-29
    2013-05-30
    2013-05-31
    .........
    ..........
    ..........
    ..........
    ..........
    2013-12-31.
```

i need some simple query without declare function and stored procedure,and with .because i want to join this  with  another query.plz anyone can find out the solution for me

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

```
select * from table_name where date between 2013-05-28 and 2014-01-01;
```

If you want more information check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp)

Comment: i think she is asking the date should be select by the  user. Not hard-corded one.

Comment: so what she has to pass through the variable

Comment: if i have the data in sql, between dates whatever i (user)will choose based on that dates will fall.but if dont have data in sql ,that should show null,            FOR EXAMPLE: 1-1-2017 to 31-1-2017  i will go to choose the dates.in that case 1-1-2017,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30 along with month and year should come,without leaving any dates

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query

```
select "date_column_name" from "table_name" where date between 2013-05-28 and 2014-01-01;
```

**Note : Replace date_column_name with column name used in your table and table_name with the name given to your table contaning your dates(without quotes).This is return you only dates from that table.**